# Why is puppeteer page.$$eval returning undefined

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm trying to create a helper function for my e2e tests using puppeteer to select an item from a select dropdown that was implemented using Material UI. For some reason, the dropdown item returns undefined. This is my function.

```
export const selectFromDropDown = async (page, selectElement, className, value) => {
  const dropdownInput = await page.waitForSelector(selectElement)
  await dropdownInput.click()
  await page.waitForSelector(`li.${className}`)

  const dropdownItem = await page.$$eval(`li.${className}`, (listItems, val) => listItems.find((item) => item.dataset.value === val), value)
  console.log(dropdownItem, '000000')
  dropdownItem.click()
}
```

I have also done `` const dropdownItem = await page.$$eval(`li.${className}`, (listItems, val) => listItems.find((item) => console.log('match: ', item.dataset.value === val) || item.dataset.value === val), value) ``. It logs false for others and true for the list item that matches the value but the dropdownItem is still undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$$eval` won't return a `handle` you will need to use `evaluateHandle`.

```js
const dropdownItem = await page.evaluateHandle(
    (listItemsSelector, val) => 
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(listItemsSelector)
            .find((item) => item.dataset.value === val), 
    `li.${className}`, 
     value)
console.log(dropdownItem, '000000')
await dropdownItem.click()
```